# SQLite - fastest way to save changes

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I'm doing Android app using local SQLite database and online DB accessed via WebService. I need to keep local DB filled with current data from online DB. I can get date and time of last change in online DB but the answer from WebService only gives me the time of last change. Not what rows/ids/... were changed. So what is the best way to update local data? Should i empty the entire SQLite DB and insert data from online DB? Or should I do UPDATE command for each row? Or is there a better way to do this?

I need it to find the fastest solution for this.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:** I can't change the online DB.

Answer (score 1):

My advice: 
Set a column in the online db table with last_update_date
Send the last update date of the local db
Return all rows that changed after that on the online db.
update or insert new records.

edit: after your edit stating you can't change the online db, i see no other way of doing it besides cleaning the local db and inserting everything from the start...

Comment: I can't do that. I can work only with the date and time that the WebService returns.